# How do novelists use syntax creatively, without dumbfounding reader?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I write fiction. In a recent workshop I was told my writing had "weird syntax" and being that my character 1st point of view is a street urchin perhaps it was unconsciously deliberate on my part, in regards to syntax. But, my question is, how do novelists use syntax creatively, without dumbfounding?

Comment: "Weird syntax" just means they don't know how to describe what they're perceiving. Syntax in general is pretty weird stuff, but probly your friend wasn't referring to real syntax. People who aren't familiar with language often use terms in vague ways, like handwaving. Novelists in my experience don't think about syntax at all; they concentrate on plot and character and occasionally dialogue.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: *unconsciously deliberate* -- There you go again (-;

Comment: If they do it on purpose, then that means they understand what will dumbfound their readers and what won’t and then they avoid the stuff that will.  So your real question is “How do I know what will dumbfound my readers?”  And the answer is, “We don’t know enough about them to make any guesses at all.”

Comment: Change the order of words, you can. But be consistent to let the reader get used to it.

Comment: Thank you all. I laughed and I didn't cry.